# What are the implications of having out of date table statistics on a Sybase/SQLServer database?

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, sybase, table-statistics

For example, for heavily used tables with volumes in the order of 10 million rows that grow by a million rows a month, if the stats are 6-8 months old how detrimental to the performance of the database is this going to be? How often should you be refreshing the stats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statistics are kept and used by the query planner, and they have a noticeable impact. I can't give you exact guidelines on how often you should refresh them. That will depend on how much work it takes to refresh them and how much impact fresh stats have on your queries. The real answer for this is to take good measurements and judge options by the results. Tinkering without measurement is a throw of the dice.

Answer (score 0):

We refresh stats every night.  No sense waiting for the Weekend if the stats could be refreshed nightly - by Friday they will be worse than they were on Monday ...

Problem is what if it takes too long?

For databases which have that problem we refresh stats on certain tables each night - so some tables are done every night, some less often.  (We have a database table of which tables to do when, and a history of how long the Stats took to regenerate, and tune the schedule accordingly)

> > if the stats are 6-8 months old how detrimental to the performance of the database is this going to be

I would be very surprised if it didn't make a huge difference on a table growing by 1 million rows-per-month

If that is your actual state I would expect that the tables need defragging too

Answer (score 0):

Implications are dire. You should be refreshing them as often as you can to give the optimizer the best information to make decisions. You will be able to find out how bad the statistics are by running the optdiag utility. Analysing the output and running again to compare over a few days or a week will let you know exactly how bad the situation is. I would recommend that at the earliest convieniance you drop and recreate the indexes and run 'update index statistics' on the table in question. This should be enough information to get you through. I am assuming that you are able to analyse the output of optdiag though.